# Typescript: How to use a symbol as a key when destructuring a hash

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```js
type UseStateTuple<T> = [T,React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>]
const StoreContext = createContext<IStore | null>(null)
interface IStore {
  people: UseStateTuple<string[]>
  // IStore could potentially have other useState tuples. Something like
  // posts: UseStateTuple<IPost[]> for example
}

interface Props {
  type: string        // this is the key that points to a useState tuple
  description: string // ignore this
}

export const AddPerson: React.FC<Props> = ({type, description}) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  // useContext(StoreContext) returns an IStore object that I want to destructure.
  // In this context (no pun intended) "[type]:" should be evaluated to "people:", right?
  //
  // I can use:
  //   "{ people }"
  //
  // instead of
  //   "[type]: [data, setData]"
  //
  // and it works. Why is that? 
  const { [type]: [data, setData] } = useContext(StoreContext)!

  /*
  // This code works fine.
  const { people } = useContext(StoreContext)!
  const [data, setData] = people
  */

  // function continues....
}

/// JSX
<AddPerson type="people" description="Here is a description..." />
```

If you need more information about this simple `useContext`/`useState` with Typescript example, the three most relevant files (and the whole project) is located [here](https://github.com/aarona/react-context-state-example/tree/Typescript/src/components). I tried to put all of the relevant code here in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally to use an index the indexing expression must be of type `keyof T` where `T` is whatever type you are indexing. Or in other words the indexing expression must provably be valid as an index of `T`.

If you change `type` to `keyof IStore` it will work:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react'

type UseStateTuple<T> = [T, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>]
const StoreContext = createContext<IStore | null>(null)
interface IStore {
  people: UseStateTuple<string[]>
  // IStore could potentially have other useState tuples. Something like
  // posts: UseStateTuple<IPost[]>
}

interface Props {
  type: keyof IStore        
  description: string 
}

export const AddPerson: React.FC<Props> = ({type, description}) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const { [type]: [data, setData] } = useContext(StoreContext)!

  return <div></div>
}

let d = () => <AddPerson type="people" description="Here is a description..." /> 

//error
let d2 = () => <AddPerson type="people2" description="Here is a description..." />
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=27&ssc=84&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDec1SoxIDCEAdsQB5ZwCuAzkgMowrHaOkXXwC+cAGZQIIOAHJC6GOICwAKAUwAnmCRwAqk1bskAFTpgANkgA8egHxwAvHADae7MmkA6ACLAGYdmgAWp5wwXZiQYHWIAQQxgCnMLCwBdBTQKBnhWaG5KJBobfCliMmyaUwBJDMI4AB84cjojIwsACjqGgEoFYGyoQXR1cphM3AU4ODUIYyQALk1tNmIDSdM0qC6AczsEixG4AHpduAGhlPqAEzGIYkpgFAblOF8UADd1S98kKHo53TgYQxMGC44MxRKFfOs4EZgABrJA7fYXNIMGZaFjzfT-MylAAKEDSm228j4Ck63V6aHU2JEYAYw3koxUahmsOUEEEhwq6lG3NGO1OSAYBGAYBgMXIMxWEIUxMU8hykFg+FS8Aip1O2I+DAoM0CMBcADESKYqRMGFZbE0cIykNh+YLViKxXw2jYrDgdilyGl7F0wHRaEwYKVyH6YAk8lxwkgmuJxB1ZaNPd68HZrQkZnZTuwUNhA25s+GBLYuEVeE1OaWcjA2gBCEn0uCEP5QchwUynYBPCymXYdrvS+smeDnC0u6xWUyq9Waii-VRIawAInGk0XcDtQsdFCXAAkPupPHAUOuBZvRRQXJe17srPX9h8RFAFEP1wAmPJNMcTqcaqBa1vWkuK4mK+a4bg657kLu+5wIex7gcKkGXi415WEAA)

You may have issues invoking the set method as it will be of a union type, so type assertions may be needed.

Comment: That actually makes more sense that it works better when you constrain `type` to an actual key in `IStore`. Still new to TS so I appreciate the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

you may want

```js
interface Props {
  type: keyof IStore        // this is the key that points to a useState tuple
  description: string // ignore this
}
```